# FBloginview not working in iOS5

Tags: objective-c, xcode, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using fb ios sdk 3.5, and i tried to run sample project named **Scrumptious**  came with the package, it uses FBLoginView for login purpose, but FBLoginView is not working on iOS5.0. When i press the FBLoginVIew, it stays pressed and nothing ops up. While its working fine for iOS6. It opens up safari for login. I have test on simulator only as i dont have device. Is it that FBloginView is just for iOS6 devices?

```
- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView {
    // Upon login, transition to the main UI by pushing it onto the navigation stack.
    SCAppDelegate *appDelegate = (SCAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:((UIViewController *)appDelegate.mainViewController) animated:NO];
}


- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView {
    // Facebook SDK * login flow *
    // It is important to always handle session closure because it can happen
    // externally; for example, if the current session's access token becomes
    // invalid. For this sample, we simply pop back to the landing page.
    SCAppDelegate *appDelegate = (SCAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    if (appDelegate.isNavigating) {
        // The delay is for the edge case where a session is immediately closed after
        // logging in and our navigation controller is still animating a push.
        [self performSelector:@selector(logOut) withObject:nil afterDelay:.5];
    } else {
        [self logOut];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "When i press the FBLoginVIew, it stays pressed and nothing ops up".

Comment: @ShireeshAsthana  I mean, in iOS5 , when i click on FBLoginView, which looks like a button, it doesnt do anything, it just stays in pressed state. In short FBLoginView is not working  in iOS5. It does not open safari, doesnt show any error,doesnt do anything. I am working on simulator.

Comment: @ShireeshAsthana If you try running scrumptious sample code which come with fb iOS sdk3.5 on iOS5 simulator then you can get a clear picture of the problem i am facing. you will see, that facebook button doesnt do anything .